# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on integer

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo problemas en una función que hace una consulta al servidor y saca unos datos dados por formulario. Este es el error que obtengo:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on integer in ...
```

Dentro de ese error también me aparece esto:

```
 miclase::obtenerActos('Baena', 'Ma\xC3\xB1ana')
```

*Baena* es la localidad, pero en el otro campo debería aparecer horario que solo puede ser Mañana, tarde o ambas, sin embargo me aparecen esos caracteres que no sé qué significan. Si hago un echo de $_POST sí me aparece bien el horario.

Tengo esta función:

```
public static function obtenerActos($localidad,$horario) 
{
    $sql2="select numacto, nombre, tipo, codbanda, localidad, dia, horario from actos where localidad LIKE '".$localidad."' and horario LIKE '".$horario."'";
    $resultado2=self::ejecutaExec($sql2);
    $arrayActos=array();
    
        while ($fila=$resultado2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
         {
              $arrayActos[]=new Acto ($fila);
         }
    
     return $arrayActos; 
}
```

La función `ejecutaExec` funciona correctamente y la sentencia también ya que en el servidor phpmyadmin me da los resultados deseados.

En el controlador tengo esto:

```
<?php
//header("Location: ../View/ver_actos.php");
require_once("../Model/base.php");
$localidad = $_POST["localidad"];
$horario = $_POST["horario"];

$arrayDatosActos=miclase::obtenerActos($localidad,$horario);

print_r ($arrayDatosActos); 

?>
```

El `while` me está dando problemas (quiero creer); he probado varias formas y tampoco, ya no sé si el problema esta ahí o en otro lado. A ver si podéis echarme una mano.

La función que utilizo para la consulta es esta:

```
protected static function ejecutaExec($sql) {

    try {
        $conexion = self::conexion();
        $registros = $conexion->exec($sql);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die ("Error:".$e->getMessage());
    }
    return $registros;

}
```

Comment: El error lo dice claramente, estás llamando a fetch() en un integer... en un número. Comprueba los datos, sacando un var_dump() de $resultado2 a ver que estás obteniendo. Una duda más, por que hay llaves abriendo y cerrando fuera del while ?? no falta o sobra algo ahí ??? `{ while(...){}... }`

Comment: si sobran es de un if que tenia antes lo edito. Voy a probar lo que me has comentado.

Comment: @Excorpion el var_dum() no me arroja ningún mensaje.

Comment: Encontré el problema, la función que ejecutaba la consulta no estaba bien...

Comment: perfecto ! hallaste solución ?

Comment: si, ahora edito!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que estaba utilizando una función para sentencias insert,alter etc en vez de utilizar una función para consultas:

```
 protected static function ejecutaQuery($sql) {

    try {
        $conexion = self::conexion();
        $resultSet = $conexion->query($sql);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Error:".$e->getMessage());
    }
    return $resultSet;
}
```

Aplicando esta función, todo funciona correctamente.